# Configuring faces in LaTeX mode

Tags: latex, faces

I use alot the `M-o i` shortcut (which, according to the key description, runs the command `facemenu-set-italic`) to emphasize parts of my text. Over the years I have changed several computers (hence OSes and distributions) and I notice that depending on the overall configuration, this command wraps the selected text (`...` below) either in

```
\emph{...}
```

or in

```
{\em ...}
```

For several (more or less technical or trivial) reasons, I prefer `\emph{...}` to `{\em ...}`, but in my current configuration I get the latter. I tried to find where this is configured, but without any success. Any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you use LaTeX a lot, I'd suggest using AUCTeX.

Comment: @andrej: Thanks for the suggestion. To be honest, I am not 100% sure, but I do believe I am already using it (for instance, I do have the RefTex mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize the variable `tex-latex-face-alist` adding this code to `.emacs`

```
(with-eval-after-load "tex-mode"
  (setq tex-latex-face-alist `((italic . "\\emph{ ")
                               ,@tex-face-alist)))
```